# Keycloak admin user creation

Tags: rest, keycloak

Can we create a admin user in keycloak using below rest-api ?

https://$HOSTNAME/auth/admin/realms/{REALM}/users

I am using the below payload , but it's now working.

> { "attributes" : {}, "emailVerified": "", "enabled": true, "username":
>   "admin", "clientRoles": {"realm-management": [ "realm-admin" ] }  }

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call a separate REST API after you create the user to add roles/groups.

See this [issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-3410).

Comment: Thank a lot @Marcos